# Grails multiple trigger with identifier for CRON

Tags: grails, triggers, cron

I have a simple Grails application which has a cron job. I have a requirement where I need to have two triggers for this crob job and In the execute method, according to which trigger, I would get information from different source. I have outlined what I need to do in the below code.

```
class sampleCronJob {

  static triggers = {
    cron name: 'trigger1' , cronExpression: "0 15 10 1 * ?"
    cron name: 'trigger2' , cronExpression: "0 45 10 1 * ?"
  }

  def execute() {
        def info
        if(name=='trigger1'){
            info = sampleService.getInfoFromTable1()
        } else {
            info = sampleService.getInfoFromTable2()
        }
        //process info
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this, where I need to get the name of the trigger, and have two triggers in this format?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can do it like you have it in mind or defined. Take a look at the mailinglist plugin, I have defined dynamic quartz schedule from the frontend form that then sets trigger to that value - maybe you could do something similar and define the trigger from outside of actual job